# How to perform actions based on segue

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, segue

Here's what I'm trying to do:

I have 2 views, Settings and Main Screen.

I've coded a segue to occur when a button in Settings is pressed, taking the view to the Main Screen. The identifier is "reset".

I'm trying to have the Main Screen perform a series of actions if this segue is triggered, but I can't find the function or way to do this.

Any help on how to implement this? I'd like it to trigger when the segue occurs.

Comment: By views do you mean controller because segue are used between controller ? And why don't you call your function in the `viewDidAppear` (or `viewWillAppear`) of your MainScreen ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass arguments to the main screen in the `prepareForSegue` function in the settings page. Then in your main screen you can put in checks in your `viewWillAppear` function to handle them as you see fit.

Example:

In Settings:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (segue.identifier == "reset") {
        // pass data to next view
        let viewController:ViewController = segue!.destinationViewController as MainViewController
        viewController.settings = settings // where settings is what you want to pass
    }
}
```

In Main Screen:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    if self.settings { // Do something }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting something to happen when the segued view controller is triggered you can do it in a couple of places.

If you want the event to happen at the time the segue is fired, perform your code inside of `prepareForSegue`. There you can check the `UIStoryboardSegue` object's identifier field for "reset" and if true, call your logic.

If you want it to happen when the destination view controller loads or appears, do it inside of its `viewDidLoad` or `viewDidAppear` methods. In your case those methods would exist on the "Main Screen" view controller class.